# Need to access an xml file over https by accepting all certs in android

Tags: android, xml, https

I have just began programming in android and I am using a code to retrieve an xml file from a https encrypted server.

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    Log.w(TAG,"xml recieved");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

I have read articles telling me about `SSLScoketFactory` and trust manager and all. Its very confusing. Can anyone tell me what or how I should proceed now? I am not worried about man in the middle attacks. I just need to retrieve the xml file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this the following way...............

**1.** If the site you are accessing, is not certified, then you need to create a Custom Certificate.

**2.** Then you need to pass the xml as a String to the Server.

Eg:

**A custom certificate class, with method to return HttpClient object**

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }


public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}

}
```

**The code to post the xml to the Server:**

```
public String postData(String url, String xmlQuery) {



        final String urlStr = url;
        final String xmlStr = xmlQuery;
        final StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();



        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                HttpClient httpclient = MySSLSocketFactory.getNewHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlStr);


try {

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xml", xmlStr));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    Log.d("Vivek", response.toString());

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream i = entity.getContent();

                    Log.d("Vivek", i.toString());
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String s = null;


                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        Log.d("YumZing", s);
                        sb.append(s);
                    }


                    Log.d("Check Now",sb+"");




                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } /*
                 * catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { // TODO
                 * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } catch
                 * (SAXException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
            }

        });

        t1.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Getting from Post Data Method "+sb.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: i have to retrieve the xml not post to the server.